# Editing older questions frowned upon?

Tags: discussion, editing

I was on the review tab and forgot I had selected "View All". So I went around editing badly formatted questions and inadvertently bumping them to the top of the front page.

Is this frowned upon by the community? Past questions are still very well indexed on search engines and people will be visiting them, so the content should still be presentable.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You edited 5 posts today, and 10 yesterday; I think we'll be fine :). Some sites get seriously bent out of shape if someone floods the homepage, but that's when a user randomly decides that 200 questions with property X need to instead have property Y, and goes and edits all of them in 10 minutes. Reviewing and editing questions are very good things (and you can finally [edit directly](https://unix.stackexchange.com/privileges/edit), which is awesome); I'm far less concerned with the home page than I am with having low quality posts. As long as you don't post an edit every 30 seconds for 15 straight minutes I don't think anybody will mind

Comment: Awesome, however I would really like to edit that much. Too bad there isn't a way to edit without a bump to front page. I would gladly go through several (and I mean lots) questions/answers to fix them. I'm all for standards.

Comment: Something like the [minor edit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:Minor_edit) checkboxes used by the wiki engines could be definitely helpful. Of course, assuming that edits marked as minor would not bump up the questions.

Comment: @manatwork http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26483/could-we-have-the-ability-to-mark-a-change-as-minor-in-questions-or-answers